# Cannot open an encrypted file on OS X

Tags: linux, macos, encryption, checksum, keepassx

I cannot decrypt files on OS X (10.6.8 and 10.8.2) which I have encrypted on Ubuntu (10.04) using [ccrypt](http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/). As a similar problem, I have a password file created with [KeePassX](http://www.keepassx.org/). I just cannot open it on OS X.

SHA256 checksums of encrypted files match, so they have not been corrupted during "transport." What could be causing this problem? Could it be, say, character encoding?

Much oblige!

Comment: It could be character encoding if your passwords contain any non-ASCII characters.

Comment: The characters in my passwords come from this character class: [a-zA-Z0-9_!]. Do you think '_' or '!' might cause some interoperability problems?

Comment: Only if one side is using an "odd" code page.